# Sum the values with underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I have JSON data like below.

```
{  
   "market":[  
      {  
         "aciklama":"Migros",
         "kategori":"market",
         "odeme_tipi":"kredi_karti",
         "tarih":{  
            "seconds":1557673429,
            "nanoseconds":599000000
         },
         "tutar":"10",
         "user_email":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "user_uid":"6xx"
      },
      {  
         "aciklama":"Pidesi",
         "kategori":"market",
         "odeme_tipi":"nakit",
         "tarih":{  
            "seconds":1557173938,
            "nanoseconds":955000000
         },
         "tutar":"5",
         "user_email":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "user_uid":"6xx"
      }
   ],
   "diger":[  
      {  
         "aciklama":"Tatlı",
         "kategori":"diger",
         "odeme_tipi":"nakit",
         "tarih":{  
            "seconds":1557591963,
            "nanoseconds":180000000
         },
         "tutar":"20",
         "user_email":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "user_uid":"6xx"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get the sum of subnodes of `market`, `diger` via `tutar` property and want to extract this result with underscore.js:

```
market: 15 
diger: 20
```

I tried [reduce](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce) function of undersore.js but I could not. What is the best way to extract child nodes and process it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to use a library for that... Pure JS :

```
let res = {};
for(let category in myObj) {
     res[category] = 0;

     for(let sub of myObj[category]) {
        res[category] += parseInt(sub.tutar, 10);             
     }
}
return res;
```

Or if you really want to use a library, this is with lodash which has a `sum` function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sumBy :

```
let res = {};
for(let category in myObj) {
     res[category] = _.sumBy(myObj[category], o => parseInt(o.tutar, 10));
}
return res;
```

Or with underscore js reduce :

```
let res = {};
for(let category in myObj) {
     res[category] = _.reduce(myObj[category], (memo, sub) => { return memo + parseInt(sub.tutar, 10); }, 0);
}
return res;
```

Comment: I taught underscore.js as if it kind of data wrangling library which works like pandas library in the python or dplyr in R. It has a lot of function which provides more clear and less code.  However, as I understand for this kind of tasks pure js should be the first choice. Do you know any JS library works like dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ ?

Comment: @SuatAtanPhD I recommend using lodash instead of underscore.js, more functions and I think it's better maintained

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure JS OFC, but here's a requested [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org) approach using [`reduce`](https://underscorejs.org/#reduce)

```js
const input = {
  "market": [{
    "aciklama": "Migros",
    "kategori": "market",
    "odeme_tipi": "kredi_karti",
    "tarih": {
      "seconds": 1557673429,
      "nanoseconds": 599000000
    },
    "tutar": "10",
    "user_email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "user_uid": "6xx"
  }, {
    "aciklama": "Pidesi",
    "kategori": "market",
    "odeme_tipi": "nakit",
    "tarih": {
      "seconds": 1557173938,
      "nanoseconds": 955000000
    },
    "tutar": "5",
    "user_email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "user_uid": "6xx"
  }],
  "diger": [{
    "aciklama": "Tatlı",
    "kategori": "diger",
    "odeme_tipi": "nakit",
    "tarih": {
      "seconds": 1557591963,
      "nanoseconds": 180000000
    },
    "tutar": "20",
    "user_email": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "user_uid": "6xx"
  }]
};

var output = _.reduce(_.pairs(input), (memo, kv) => {
  const key = kv[0];
  memo[key] = _.reduce(kv[1],
    (memo1, o) => memo1 + parseInt(o.tutar),
    0);
  return memo;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```